# Updating a variable based on a variable that is inside a function?

Tags: python

What I'm looking for is to update a variable that is based outside of a function using variables that are within a function. Using the sample code below as an example, I want to make it so that when the user keys in 1 for menuNav, currentMenuState gets subsequently updated based on menuState, so that it gets updated from ACCOUNTSMENU to VIEWMENU.

```
currentMenuState = 'ACCOUNTSMENU'

def AccountMenu(menuState):
    print ("1. View")
    print ("2. Edit")
    print ("3. Help")
    print ("4. Quit")
    menuNav = int(input())
    if menuNav == 1:
        menuState = 'VIEWMENU'
    elif menuNav == 2:
        menuState = 'EDITMENU'
    elif menuNav == 3:
        print ("Hint text")
    elif menuNav == 4:
        print ("Closed the program and terminated all processes.")
        menuState = 'IDLE'
    else:
        print ("Invalid input.")
        pass
    return menuState

while currentMenuState != 'IDLE':
    if currentMenuState == 'ACCOUNTSMENU':
        AccountMenu(currentMenuState)
    elif...
```

While I could've just used global variables to save the trouble, **I was advised against using global variables.** So I'm not sure what other way there is to get around this issue, since currentMenuState doesn't update, and just stays as is.

Comment: Look into using a class, then you can use the instances variables and can avoid globals

Comment: You `return` the menustate, which is a great way to pass variables to a place outside the scope of your function. However, you have to define what you want to do with the returned value. (hint: set it to currentMenuState!) `currentMenuState = AccountMenu('ACCOUNTSMENU')